# What is the font used in the Adicto logo?

Tags: font-identification, logo, sans-serif

What font is used in this logo? I'd love to have this logo or a similar one.

[image: Adicto Logo]

Thanks!

Comment: You'd "love to have" that logo? I think Adicto may have a problem with that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The font is House Industries' [Neutraface](http://www.houseind.com/fonts/neutraface):

[image: Neutraface Screenshot]

That's Neutra Display Bold. If the weight looks a little off, try another weight in the family like Neutra Text Demi or Neutra Text Bold.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need the same font exactly myfonts.com detects these two as similar ones -

[image]

[Simplo Bold](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/durotype/simplo/bold/)